# how to use Picasso to load favicon.ico icon in android app

Tags: android, picasso, favicon

using picasso to load image from remote url, it works fine except if the image is favicon.ico

is it the picasso does not handle favico type of file?

```
favIconUrl = "http://www.cnn.com/favicon.ico";

  Picasso.with(mContext)
         .load(favIconUrl)
         .into(target);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did trace, looks like picasso does not handle it:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(mContext).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {

         Log.i("onImageLoadFailed(), uri:"+uri+", exception:"+exception);
                                            }
     }).build();
```

onImageLoadFailed(), uri:https://www.yahoo.com/favicon.ico, exception:java.io.IOException: Failed to decode stream.

Answer (score 3):

A **favicon.ico** could be multiple file formats. **PNG**, **GIF**, **JPEG** etc ([See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support)). Picasso does the fetching, but your target (an ImageView) may not support the format of the .ico file referenced.